# How to work in locale/remote and have the work always synchronized

Tags: django, git, rsync, sshfs

this is a newbie question.

I've a server where I've uploaded all my work directory. It's a small project in Django.

I want to work either in locale and in remote server, but I want the both directories ever synchronized. When I'm going to work on my computer, I would the work directory to be synchronized. And vice versa.

Someone says me to use `sshfs`, `rsync`, `git`.

What are your recommendations? Which one should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using git (or another version control system) *anyway*, to ensure that you always have a record of the changes you make to your work. Synchronising across systems is an added benefit that you will get if you set up the git remotes properly, and always ensure that you pull from the remote when you start and push back when you finish.

Comment: Can you link me an easy tutorial for setting up git on my server and begin to use it? By the way, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest answer for complete synchronization between them... Drop Box :)

But git might serve you well.  Especially if you want to expand on this someday to have a QA vs. Production server that you stage changes across.  That topic is a big one that's been answered a few times here.  Do a search for "git production deploy" to get a list of questions around that topic.

Comment: Thanks. Probably git is the way. Now should I understand how to use it on my server and locally.